# Drop down to select the nearest city

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

Currently I have the code to select the city of the user from the drop down options.

But if the user is clicking from the cities that are not in the drop down options, it selects the first option in the drop down.

Is there anyway to make it select the nearest option in the drop down list?

Here is the Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uZLNM/104/

```
<title></title>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <select name="country" id="country" class="inputCombo">    
            <option value="Sioux Falls">Sioux Falls</option>
            <option value="Green Bay">Green Bay</option>
            <option value="Brooklyn">Brooklyn</option>
            <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Lincoln">Lincoln</option>
            <option value="US">United States</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Script:

```
var url = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(url).success(function(data) {
        var country_code = data.geoplugin_city;
        var $country = $('#country');
        $country.find('option[value="' + country_code + '"]').prependTo($country);

        $country.val(country_code);
    });
 });
```

Comment: ....wut? Your fiddle works perfectly. Are you wanting the drop down to select a city when the user clicks *close* to the dropdown? Cause that would confuse people... Also "drop down to select the nearest city

" isn't a question, so I would edit that to say what you are actually asking. Which (I think) is "How do you select the option closest to the mouse if the mouse is outside of the select element" But, again, I'm not even sure if that's what you are asking...

Comment: @NativeCoder here is what i want the fiddle to do. for example if the user is accessing the site from New York, the fiddle automatically selects New york in the drop down list. Now if the user is accessing from a city that is not in the drop down list, I want the fiddle to select the nearest city from user's location. I hope this helps.

Comment: oooooooooh. Well, you'll probably need some sort of location API. Zippopotam.us is great if you have access to their zip code. But that's gonna give you their exact city, not the closest. You may have to compile the list yourself. Goodluck!

Comment: @NativeCoder is there a way we can give different Urls for different locations like example.com/om for Omaha and example.com/kc for Kansas city and direct them to a same page??

Comment: huh? What are you talking about?

Comment: never mind got it.